# How to save a file in local storage through a save dialog box using Flutter?

Tags: file, filesystems, flutter

I am creating an XML file in my app and I am able to save it using path provider, but I want to give user, the ability to save the file at desired location.

- As the user clicks the save button, a save dialog box should appear.
- User can see the local device storage(internal as well as external(SD card)) and go to a desired location
- User can enter a file name and the file should get saved in the location selected by user

Same way, I want to open the file using open dialog box.

[Here is a screen shot from **Microsoft Excel app**, I want somewhat like that only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE4X7.jpg)

[Save Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNs9A.jpg)

[Open Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wySPx.jpg)

Comment: Any news on that?